# How to print meta_key from Wordpress DB?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have found a solution, but I don't think it's very fast, as I use a query to select all data from the db and then run another `select` (`get_post_meta` as I understand makes another db query) in loop to print `_wp_geo_longitude`.

Is there a simple fast way to print `meta_value` by key in result query loop like this: `$query->meta_value['_wp_geo_longitude']`? Thanks.

```
 $out=''; // output data
     $args = array(
        'numberposts'       => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'post_date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters'  => true,
        'meta_key'          => '_wp_geo_longitude',
        'meta_key'          => '_wp_geo_latitude',

    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $out.=  get_the_title() .'  -  '.get_post_meta(get_the_id(), '_wp_geo_longitude', true). '<br>';
        }
    } else {
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```